# A different kind of shared ownership

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

The `shared_ptr` in C++ comes to solve a problem, multiple deletes when multiple objects take ownership of an object. It does so by making only the last delete happen.
There is another flavor to that pointer is when an object wants ownership but doesn't want to delay a delete so it takes a weak pointer which notifies him when its deleted to prevent problems.
There is another way of doing this. Instead of making only the last delete happen, make only the first delete happen and the rest of the objects should be notified that it happened just like weak pointer does.
This is useful for object like a connection, that if one end releases it, it should be destroyed while the other end knows about this.
Is there anything like this in C++ or Boost?

Comment: Can't you implement a simple pointer wrapper that check's if it's pointing to a NULL memory address before using it? So, if any object destroy the pointer, i.e. makes it point to a NULL location, all other objects will know that pointer has already been deleted.

Comment: While a smart-ptr to a wrapped ptr solves this problem for the single-threaded case, a thread-safe solution is quite a bit more complicated... BTW: Answer to the question is a no.

Comment: You could issue a signal from object's destructor. See Boost.Signals

Comment: Is there something wrong with `boost::weak_ptr`?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern could be modeled with a single shared, mutexed `shared_ptr` used only to create and destroy the object and a `weak_ptr` for each client/endpoint, used for access.

Note that such a scheme would cause excessive locking and might not give the semantics you want. You would need to `lock` the `weak_ptr` during use, which touches the `shared_ptr` internal mutex. When one side destroys the master `shared_ptr` instance, the object persists while any read operations finish.

The more conventional solution would be to transmit a hang-up message over the channel itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of *notifications*:

- synchronous
- asynchronous
- on-demand (not really a notification)

Depending on what you really want, the implementation can vary a lot.

The latter (on-demand) is already available through the typical `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` dichotomy: when accessing the object through the `weak_ptr`, you'll know if it has been deleted meanwhile.

The other two can be implemented through an Observer pattern on top of a traditional `shared_ptr`, however they have complexity and performance consequences, so I would make sure that the need is real before using them.